# Use many variables outside map function laravel

Tags: laravel

So, in my laravel project, I need to use some variables outside map collection. I have tried to get the solution from many stackoverflow posts. But all of them only show a way for using 1 variable outside map collection like code below.

```
$x = 'test';
$collection = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) use ($x) {
    return $item + $x;
});
```

Do you guys have any solution for this?

Comment: for simple callbacks like this you can use [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but maybe you are looking for `use ($x,$y,$z)`